# Game free publishing website?

Tags: publishing, free-to-play

I am making game that will be completely free and I want to publish it. The publishing platform have to be free and it can be done without any contract or specific license. I simply upload my files make my game page and that’s all. Thanks for help, Maratonec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [itch.io](https://itch.io) is what you are looking for.

- No listing fee.
- No approval process.
- You don't sign away any of your IP rights.
- You don't have to promise exclusivity.
- You can choose if people can play/download your game for free, for a fixed price or for a pay-what-you-want optional donation.
- If you choose to monetize your game, you can set a commission percentage to whatever you think itch.io deserves for their services.

Comment: Can I upload there Java games?

Comment: @Maratonec If the game comes in form of a file people can download and run, then you can.

Comment: Thanks you! I am looking on the site